# Scrapy following link not getting data

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to follow a list of links and scrap data from each link with a simple scrapy spider but I am having trouble.

In the scrapy shell when I recreate the script it sends the get request of the new url but when I run the crawl I do not get any data back from the link. The only data I get back is from the starting url that was scraped before going to the link.

How do I scrape data from the link?

```
 import scrapy

    class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "players"
        start_urls = ['http://wiki.teamliquid.net/counterstrike/Portal:Teams']

        def parse(self, response):
            teams = response.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]')
            for team in teams.css('span.team-template-text'):
                yield{
                    'teamName': team.css('a::text').extract_first()
                }


            urls = teams.css('span.team-template-text a::attr(href)')
            for url in urls:
                url = response.urljoin(url)
                yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_team_info)


        def parse_team_info(self, response):
                yield{
                    'Test': response.css('span::text').extract_first()
                }
```

Comment: always use tag `python` - it highlights code and makes more readable.

Comment: use `print()` to display values in variables and which part of code is executed - it helps to find problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using

```
url = response.urljoin(url)
yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_team_info)
```

use

```
yield response.follow(url, callback=self.parse_team_info)
```